# If the [subtree] tag falls, does it make a sound?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed the [subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subtree) tag when writing a question about git subtrees.

There is already a tag specific to git subtrees ([git-subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-subtree)) but most of the questions with the subtree tag are related to git subtrees.

There does seem to be some theoretical concept relating to the concept of sub-trees within the broader subject of tree data structures.

My question: is it appropriate to label git subtree questions with the subtree tag? Or are all these people doing it wrong?

Comment: Clearly, a "subtree" is a portion of a "tree", so yes, it relates to tree data structures. But that doesn't answer the *real* question: is it a good tag? I'm tempted to say no—why would you ever use the [tag:subtree] tag without using the [tag:tree] tag? And if not, what does the additional tag add to the question? Nothing, in my opinion.

Comment: Looks like it's time to clear the forest of all the sub tress.

Comment: @COdyGray furthermore a tree without subtree isn't really a tree :)

Comment: [Mu.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#.22Unasking.22_the_question)

Comment: To subtree or not to subtree, that is the question.

Comment: @deceze that link lead me to the author Douglas Hofstadter and now my mind is being blown. TY

Comment: @Walfrat, the empty tree is a tree without a sub-tree. The tree consisting of a single node is also a tree without a sub-tree. Just saying :)

Comment: @morxa i know morxa, i know, more likely a tree that can't have subtree can't bue called a tree :p

Comment: I'd say that each tree is a subtree of itself. However. I'm *so* tempted to upvote this just for the title. But won't do it. Because I don't think that it should be burninated. I won't downvote it either. Because I don't think that it should not be burninated. If there was a "Mu" button, I'd press it.

Comment: A subtree is a tree. There's no need for a separate tag for it.

Comment: `tree` should be added to all questions that have `subtree`? Can a question be about a *subtree* but not about an entire tree?  If so, then, analogous, `subtree` can be removed from those same questions.